# Number appears in the browser but not in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

in browser:

```
<p class="large bugunku-test-sayisi">116.565</p>
```

in python result:

```
<p class="large bugunku-test-sayisi"></p>
```

Python Code:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://covid19.saglik.gov.tr/')
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
test = source.find(attrs={"class":"large bugunku-test-sayisi"})
print(test)
```

i couldn't understand where the problem is i will be glad if you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the page elements are being populated asynchronously using JavaScript. Fortunately for you, the data you're looking for is baked into the HTML:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://covid19.saglik.gov.tr/"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

begin = response.text.find("var sondurumjson = ") + 19
end = response.text.find(";", begin)

data = json.loads(response.text[begin:end])
print(data[0]["gunluk_test"])
```

Output:

```
116.565
>>>
```